# Aligning DIVs vertically

Tags: css

How do I align the red box with the gray box vertically?

http://jsfiddle.net/sLZzK/1/

**I need several box combinations like that on my page, which is why I cannot simply push the red box up manually. A negative margin won't work either, since I do not know in advance how much content will be in the gray box. And the red box must overlap other page content, hence the absolute positioning.** (http://jsfiddle.net/xMm82/)

CSS:

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}
.left_div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.right_div {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 311px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left_div">gray box
  <div class="right_div">red box</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using `absolute` positioning for such structure? In the case the better solution is to use `float: left` for each div. If you want to have two divs aligned vertically use `display: table-cell` rule. Here it is:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sLZzK/9/)

UPDATE: Try to use this:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xMm82/2/)

Comment: Because the reg box must overlap things.

Comment: Works great, behaves exactly as I want it to. x)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left_div">gray box</div>
    <div class="right_div yellow">red box</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container:not(:last-child){margin-bottom: 10px;}
.left_div,.right_div{float:left;}
.clr{clear:both;}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/xMm82/1/)

Comment: I have several gray/boxes with this positioning on my page. This is why I can't push it up like that.

Comment: why dont you keep red box out of gray box?

Comment: They form a unit. Also, please the edit to my post. However, I don't feel like married to my CSS, if there is a solution with a totally different approach, I'd be thankful to see it.

Comment: It's just several "<div class="left_div">gray box<div class="right_div">red box</div></div>" below each other. See http://jsfiddle.net/xMm82/

Answer (score 0):

what I've understood is you want gray box on top of Red box:

- first of all wrap them in a parent div.
- set the width of wrapper to desirable width.
- set width to 100%(both red and gray) and you are done !! ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/sLZzK/4/))

If you want to arrange them horizontally:

- `left_div` will be wrapper
- it will contain 2 child `div`'s
- left one will have content and right one will be red box.([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iiison/sLZzK/5/))

Answer (score 0):

use float to arrange vertically and clear:both to prevent any errors
here's the corrected one

```
.left{
    float:left;
     width: 300px;
}
.right{
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
}
.left_div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.right_div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

<div class="left">
    <div class="left_div">

    </div>    
</div>
<div class="right">
    <div class="right_div">

    </div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLZzK/8/

Answer (score 0):

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/sLZzK/14/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left_div">gray box</div>
  <div class="right_div">red box</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid #369;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper > div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

You might also want to read about [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which will give you a similar and more consistent result, however it's not fully supported on various browsers yet.

Comment: Are inline-block and vertical-align well supported by browsers?

Comment: Indeed, on IE7 though, you can only assign inline-block to natively inline elements(a,span,b,i etc) and not to block ones (div,p, ul etc..)so if you want IE7 support - just change the div tags into spans.